# How can I make XMLHttpRequest perform a GM_xmlhttpRequest with the standard syntax?

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to do something weird. I'm working on a bot which helps you quickly pinpoint plagiarism on the new Stack Overflow Documents site. It's a user-script. [User scipts have special JS functions](https://wiki.greasespot.net/Greasemonkey_Manual:API).

The bot is meant to work by opening a Document page, reading each document in 30 word chunks, opening a Google tab, then perform a verbatim search and report any results back to the SO tab, where the bot either helps you edit the document to cite the source, or flag it if there's too much cited stuff.

But of course, I can't communicate between SO and Google tabs the usual way (due to cross domain policies) so I went a weird route: I used the special GM function [GM_xmlhttpRequest](https://wiki.greasespot.net/GM_xmlhttpRequest) to load Google in the SO tab (`GM_xmlhttpRequest` ignores the same origin policy), put the page in an iframe, and do the search from there. I think this approach may work, but there's a snag:

The issue is that when you perform a search in the Google iframe, Google's search requests are sent from the `http://stackoverflow.com/` domain, not Google.com. I could find those requests in Google's code and change them to specifiy `http://www.google.com` but then we would run into the same origin policy restriction again. So I want to replace the window's `XMLHttpRequest` method with `GM_xmlhttpRequest` which we can easily do but the two functions are used with different syntax:

`XMLHttpRequest` works like this:

```
var oReq = new XMLHttpRequest();
oReq.addEventListener("load", reqListener);
oReq.open("GET", "http://www.example.org/example.txt");
oReq.send();
```

while `GM_xmlhttpRequest` works like this:

```
GM_xmlhttpRequest({
    method: "GET",
    url: "https://www.google.com",
    headers: {
        "User-Agent": "Mozilla/5.0",
        "Accept": "text/xml"
    },
    onload: function(response) {
    }
});
```

My question is:

How can I package `GM_xmlhttpRequest` in such a way so as to replace `XMLHttpRequest` with it and have any scripts using `XMLHttpRequest` continue to work?